# Swift Realm 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0)

Tags: swift, realm, microsoft-translator

I am using Microsoft's translator API in my app and I use this code to generate access token:

```
func getAccessToken(){

    let key = "---"
    let requestUrl = URL(string: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken")
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")

    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else{
            return
        }
        let token = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))

        let realm = try! Realm()

        let accessToken = AccessToken()

        accessToken.value = token!

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(accessToken)
        }
    }


    task.resume()
}
```

After this I use my getAccessToken function in viewDidLoad method and then I try to access my access token like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let accessTokenObject = realm.objects(AccessToken.self)

let accessToken = accessTokenObject[0].value

print(accessToken)
```

But I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0)'

How can I solve this error? I understand that my getAccessToken function doesn't create the access token but I don't understand why.

Comment: Did you try printing `token` ? may be it's not going inside the block.

Comment: Are you sure your asynchronous network request actually finishes execution before you tried retrieving the value? Also, don't use Collection[0] to access the first element, use `accessToken.first` with safe unwrapping.

Comment: `accessTokenObject[0]` means that the **accessTokenObject** MUST contains AT LEAST 1 element inside of it. But how do you think if the **accessTokenObject** contains nothing? This happens when the async task **hasn't finished yet** but you start querying the data from database. You can use `accessTokenObject.first` (which is an optional value to avoid the error, like @David said above), and make sure you do query after your token is successfully written to database.

Comment: @ngbaanh Thank you for your help. How can I check if the async task is finished or not to start query?

Comment: @thekmb Make a **completion handler** to ensure your first-task is done before you start the second-task. See more: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94

Answer (score -2):

This code is working swift code to get a token:

```
var azureToken = String()

//Method to get an Azure token.

func getAccessToken() -> String {

print("********get azure token selected********")

let azureKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
let postString = azureKey
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" )!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue(postString, forHTTPHeaderField:"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in

    print("This is the data ********->", data as Any)
    print("This is the response ********->", response as Any)
    print("This is the error ********->", error as Any)

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")

        return
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    azureToken = responseString!

}

task.resume()

return azureToken
}
```